# View and CCK select list

Tags: views

i have created a content type in which i have a field with a select list. I create views for each option i have on the select list and am not sure how to go about it.

Example - Select list options - car, bicycle, motorcycle

View displaying all cars
view displaying all bicycles
view displaying all motorcycles

i Have tried using taxonomy but i keep getting ajax errors hence why i created a cck select list.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a page view, add all of the fields you wish to display. Then add a filter in the Filter Criteria area that includes this field, then set the Operator to once specific selection (e.g. cars). Clone each page and override this filter for each page to filter for the other selections. (You could also just create on page view and expose the filter for users to change it on the fly.)

Comment: ah, beat me to it

Answer (score 2):

Go to Add new view, give it a name, Show Content of type YOURCONTENTTYPE, Create a page = yes, give it a URL and then click continue and edit. Pick which fields you want shown (or full rendered entity etc) and display style (show as a grid, table etc). Add a filter criteria and choose the select list field (or taxonomy term if you want to go back to that way) and expose it. This will now give you a page (the url you chose) where users can click a dropdown list to get the list of items.

If you wanted to go back to using taxonomy you could easily do so without even touching views. Basically you would let the users choose a taxonomy term from the vocabulary and clicking that taxonomy link on the node page will go to a taxonomy listing all the nodes tagged with that term. If you want to use views to do the same you need to start using contextual filters and depth modifiers (see the default taxonomy view as an example).

Comment: Settled on using taxonomy vs cck select lists, easier to manipulate, thanks.

Comment: i am trying to use the default taxonomy view but am not sure whether i need to change path from the default taxonomy/term/% to something else? thanks in advance.